# how to implement scipy.ndimage.convolve1d

Tags: c++, implementation, scipy.ndimage

I have a code on python I like to convert it to  c++.

I have a probleme in this line how can I implement it in cpp.

```
    y = scipy.ndimage.convolve1d(x1, x2, mode="constant")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use OpenCV [filter2D](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga27c049795ce870216ddfb366086b5a04) function. Also you can try it in python to see if it does the thing that you want, it's pretty fast.

But if you want to implement the 1d convolution, the naïve implementation is just basically two nested for loops. [Discrete convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution?oldformat=true#Discrete_convolution).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).